# Story set in future Earth: in an enclosed megalopolis, an old man sends simulacra pigeons in the unhabitable outside, one day a real bird comes back

Tags: story-identification

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85638/98028) was initially asking for two separate works, was trimmed down to one and reopened. As OP never came back but still provided a decent enough summary of the second question, I'm reposting it so that it doesn't get lost:

> The second story is also set in a future Earth, where people live in a huge enclosed megalopolis. The outside is uninhabitable (nuclear war? pollution?) and the people who live inside are only concerned with their artificial world. However, one eccentric old man (who I think remembers how it used to be) has a hobby of sending artificial, simulacra pigeons outside. One day a real bird comes back with the simulacra, showing that the outside is habitable once more.

OP originally indicated that they read it "many years ago as a teenager", for what it's worth (i.e. [not much](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cJ9t.jpg)).

Comment: Yes, I know that not being the OP I'll never know for certain, but the description provided seems decent enough so that if an answer is posted and it seems like a good enough match, I'll accept it.